# The operator '..' is not working in flutter - dart code

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking at the following video where they use the `..` operator inside initState()

https://youtu.be/uz4xRnE-UIw?t=117

in my code it does not work!

here is my code:

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // select where the video is coming from  asset/file/network
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset(asset); 
    ..setListener( ()=> setState(() {})); // error: expected an identifier
    ..setLooping(true);  // error: expected an identifier
    ..initialize();  // error: expected an identifier
  }
```

[image: broken operator]

[image: video image]

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `;` after each line, in order to use  `..` you don't need to use `;` at the end of line, so try this:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // select where the video is coming from  asset/file/network
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset(asset)
    ..setListener( ()=> setState(() {})) 
    ..setLooping(true)
    ..initialize();  
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have extra supply of `;`

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // select where the video is coming from  asset/file/network
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset(asset)
    ..setListener( ()=> setState(() {})); // error: expected an identifier
    ..setLooping(true);  // error: expected an identifier
    ..initialize();  // error: expected an identifier
  }
```